# ionic2 view child with virtualScroll

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am having multiple virtual scrolls in a component. I am trying to use Viewchild and call update method of virtual scroll:

```
@ViewChild(VirtualScroll) virtualLists: VirtualScroll;
```

The above is getting me the first virtual list element only.
I want to access the remaining virtual lists as well. So I tried to add  #myLists to the ion-list element. And tried to access the same using the below:

```
@ViewChild('myLists') virtualFavLists: VirtualScroll;
```

But this time its giving me the ElementRef object and it is not having the update method of virtualscroll.
Is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: Try with @ ViewChildren instead of @ ViewChild if you want to get all the instances of the VirtualScroll. [Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChildren-decorator.html).

Comment: thanks for answer. It worked!

Comment: Glad to hear that :) I've added the same but as an answer so we can close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `@ViewChildren` instead of `@ViewChild` if you want to get all the instances of the VirtualScroll. You can find more information [in Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChildren-decorator.html).